# How to add custom response headers to an API published in AWS gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Can someone explain how to add custom headers to an api published in AWS gateway.

I did following steps:
1. Added headers under 404(as i want to add header when unauthorised) in"Gateway Responses".

After that, i accessed the URL and checked. I couldn't see the response headers that i added.

Can someone help me in this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add a custom header for 404 Status Code using API Gateway's Gateway Response. The header can be a static value in single quotes or it can be a [requestParameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/integration/#requestParameters).

Ensure that the API is deployed after modifying the Gateway Response.